# @Transactional method with cycle and DB persist style

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data

So today we argued a bit about one piece of code.
We have a @transactional method inside a spring service. I need style 1.
In my implemtation I need something like:

1.
@Transactional
for(each):repository.persistObjectOneByOne(object)

2.
@Transactional
repository.persistList(list)

Is style 1 very wrong or the hibernate/spring-data will deal with it in one fast and nice connection?

Answer (score 1):

if your service method is annotated with Transactional (which is in my opinion the right thing) then both styles are the same regarding the commit, the whole business unit will be wrapped under the transaction which means any operation done will not be committed unless the transaction is done.

Regarding speed in both cases the Spring Data jpa will persist each object in different query.

Comment: I also sait it today I was 90% sure but didn't take a look in the code behind the jpa save. are you 99% or 100% sure?

Comment: this is not behind the save , its the transaction concept, changes wont be visible until the commit is performed for the transaction